# OpenAPITools - ¿Por qué falla "transferCache" en los servicios generados?

Tags: java, angular, typescript, openapi

Espero que alguno pueda echarme una mano con este problema o al menos orientarme a qué puede ser.
El caso es el siguiente:
En un proyecto Angular con back de Java Spring estamos usando OpenAPI, al ejecutar el comando en Agular 16 (la dependencia es "@openApiTools") genera todo correctamente, pero se genera una variable llamada "transferCache" en los servicios generados automaticamente para la que no tenemos referencia de su existencia en back y que debemos comentar para que no de fallo al compilar el proyecto Angular. he intentando buscar información pero no hay nada que hable de esta variable.
Sale más veces en los servicios pero como variable opcional, por lo que no da error.

**Código autogenerado que tiene la variable transferCache**

```
let localVarPath = `/usuarios/${this.configuration.encodeParam({name: "usuarioId", value: usuarioId, in: "path", style: "simple", explode: false, dataType: "number", dataFormat: "int64"})}/autorizaciones`;
    return this.httpClient.request<any>('put', `${this.configuration.basePath}${localVarPath}`,
        {
            context: localVarHttpContext,
            body: autorizacionUsuario,
            responseType: <any>responseType_,
            withCredentials: this.configuration.withCredentials,
            headers: localVarHeaders,
            observe: observe,
            transferCache: localVarTransferCache,
            reportProgress: reportProgress
        }
    );
```

**Estructura del request donde no está la variable transferCache (index.d.ts)**

```
request<R>(method: string, url: string, options: {
    body?: any;
    headers?: HttpHeaders | {
        [header: string]: string | string[];
    };
    context?: HttpContext;
    reportProgress?: boolean;
    observe: 'events';
    params?: HttpParams | {
        [param: string]: string | number | boolean | ReadonlyArray<string | number | boolean>;
    };
    responseType?: 'json';
    withCredentials?: boolean;
}): Observable<HttpEvent<R>>;
```

Gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y coloca el código _como texto, con formato_. [No todos pueden ver las imágenes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976).